# How to include a .so lib in Intellij IDEA for Android project?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-ndk

I have an Android project that loads a custom .so lib. I'm having trouble w/ IntelliJ IDEA to include this .so as part of the build.

Does anyone know where to config the project settings to include this .so file?

Thanks

UPDATE: Found it!

In Project Structure -> Modules -> Android -> Native libs directory.

My project is referring to a .so from another project, that's why the path needs to be updated here to find the .so file

Comment: You should move your solution to an answer and accept it, so that other people having this problem can find it easier and the question doesn't remain unanswered in the system.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solution:

In Project Structure -> Modules -> Android -> Native libs directory.

My project is referring to a .so from another project, that's why the path needs to be updated here to find the .so file

Comment: this includes it as part of the build but how do I use the libraries inside? Trying to do an `import org.certainlibrary....` simply is not there

Comment: @GeorgePligor someone certainly need to reed a bit about JNI

Comment: @GeorgePligor you will need to load the .so lib in your java code, something like:

static {
    System.loadLibrary("libcurl");
}